# Where can I find the source code of something like this (Google Map API) or is there a better method?

Tags: google-maps

Where can I find the source code of something like this (Google Map API):

http://gmaps-utility-library.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/labeledmarker/1.1/examples/airportmap.html

What's the easiest way of marking spots in a Google Map API (embedded in my web site), according to a list of places and dates?

I think its basically a Google map APi with a labelmarker.

Answer (score 0):

> What's the easiest way of marking
>   spots in a Google Map API (embedded in
>   my web site), according to a list of
>   places and dates?

Perhaps the "easiest" way is the static approach

http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/simplewizard/makestaticmap.html

But (if you know java) a more flexible and extensible way is to use GWT,
I recomend you to install full netbeans(with Glasfish), GWT, GWT4NB, googlemaps_gwt_2_2_1

Here is an example source that is very similar to yours

http://code.google.com/p/gwt-google-apis/wiki/MapsGettingStarted